# Why is code highlighted in preview, but not in the actual post?

Tags: bug, status-completed, editor, syntax-highlighting

I'm editing my answer to [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/288087/how-do-i-set-the-first-value-of-autonumber-in-access) and wonder why code blocks are highlighted in the editor's preview, but not in the answer itself. Is it a bug? I don't remember ever having seen code blocks highlighted on SU, as is being done on SO. ( Although I must say I like highlighted code blocks better than the query-soup without it! ;) )

In the actual answer:

> [image: Answer]

In the editor's preview:

> [image: Preview]

Comment: I wonder if [forcing the code-block language](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/981/syntax-highlighting-language-hints/75019#75019) works on SU... I keep meaning to test it.

Comment: @DMA57361 Nope, doesn't work :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I don't remember ever having seen code blocks highlighted on SU, as is being done on SO.

I'm pretty sure they were, way in the beginning. But they haven't been for a while now.

And after the next build, they won't be highlighted in the preview either :)

Comment: That's too bad :( I liked it

Comment: Why not, does not seem like it can hurt.